# Bug: Can't ask questions using Midori browser

Tags: bug, status-declined, javascript

When using Midori on Ubuntu (9.10), I can't ask a question because when I try to add a tag, the tags text field doesn't clear...I can still erase all the text in there and add my own tags, but since it didn't clear correctly, the site still thinks that I haven't added tags, so the form won't submit. Instead, I get a validation message saying that I need to add tags.

Should be pretty easy to replicate as it happens to me every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it works OK in Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE7/8, and Firefox, I would rate this as a bug in Midori, not us.

Comment: +1 - I don't care if it's a bug or not. It's absolutely your problem if you refuse to use a standard browser. Supporting a browser that **isn't Google's first result for its freaking name** is hardly worth it.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the problem right? I also would like to get around this problem because Midori is a great lightweight browser. So anyone have any solutions for the Midori browser?

Comment: the tag entry system is about to change. Does it work here? Regardless, we only support the "big 5" browsers; use anything else at your own risk.